# How to track traffic from Gmail that goes through the Display Network

Tags: google-analytics

I was looking at my AdWords clicks, and I've recently gotten some big spikes in clicks coming from coming from Gmail (both mail.google.com and the gmail app, com.google.android.gm).

However when I looked at my Google Analytics, I can't see ANY entrances coming from gmail on the display network.

[Graph showing my recent spikes in clicks from Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vqPD.png)

It's seriously confusing me. Can someone tell me why this is happening, and how to differentiate traffic that's coming from gmail via the display network?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify, if you are talking about Adwords Ads in Gmail (https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7019460) or you are thinking about some email campaign (and you would like to track such traffic coming from gmail users to your website).

Please also specify if you are using auto-taging in Google Ads (Adwords) or you manually track your campaigns.

Because if you are using Adwords auto-taging then all traffic coming from Adwords is visible in reports: Acquisition > Google Adwords.

If you are not using auto-taging, then please tag your campaigns manually (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033981?hl=en).

Last but not least, I can here recommend to create also separate campaign for all "Gmail Ads campaigns".

I am not sure, if this is answer on your issue. But more details will be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: 1. I am talking about adwords ads in gmail via the google display network.
2. I am using auto-tagging.

I can track traffic coming from all of my placements. But not gmail, this picture will show the problem in a lot more detail:
https://www.screencast.com/t/yzGtQGylO